# Why does Receive GI from Lightmaps result in artifacts on this tree while Receive GI from Light Probes fix it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting

I'm baking light for some demo scenes in an asset pack I'm working on, and when it's done I notice artifacts (shadowy spots in top imaage) on these round static trees. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY78Y.png)

Top Image is when the trees receive GI from lightmaps - and get shadowy splotches - while the Bottom Image is when trees receive GI from light probes. I'm baking the GI with the Shadowmask Lighting Mode, and only one Directional Light creates soft shadows.

The settings for the shadows are:

- Baked Shadow Angle is 0
- Shadow Strength is 0.85
- Bias is 0.05
- Normal Bias is 0.4
- Near Plane is 0.2

There is another directional light in the scene but its shadow type is set to No Shadows

I tried tweaking other settings such as increasing lightmap resolution, setting it to be a static object. I've also enabled "Generate Lightmap UVs" for the Tree's model so I don't believe it's an issue with the tree model's UVs being unwrapped properly. Based on other questions here, I tried baking lights without Ambient Occlusion but that did not completely remove the artifacts. Only receiving GI from light probes seemed to solve it.

Could someone explain to me how do I get the bottom image from using lightmaps as GI? I don't want to use light probes for GI because as I understand, they are intended for dynamic lighting and are more expensive as a result. Thanks in advance!